# Can't access text field over HTML5 Video element on iPhone

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I'm building a page with a full width background video. To achieve this i've positioned the video absolutely, stretched it, and given it a negative z-index. As page content I've added a form.

```
<style type="text/css"></style> 
    #video-background{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        z-index: -1000;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<video id="video-background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" muted="muted" volume="0">
    <source src="../../css/video/globe.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<form action="#">

    <input type="email" name="email" value="Enter your email address">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Email">

</form>
```

When I access this page on an iPhone (Safari) and try to tap into the textfield, I can't focus into the element. It's as if something were either blocking the element or blocking the touch event. Text placed here is also not selectable.

Relative positioning the form and giving it a higher z-index doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
form{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I've tested this page on iPhone 4 and 5, both running iOS 7.0.4.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you use position relative for a parent (container) where is a video element?

Comment: Hi, no, as the video is the background to the entire page.

Comment: ok I know what you want to do. Try set a position relative for a parent video example create div and add class container, set width and heigth 100% and position relative. Move video element inside this div. I can help you but I need see more code - your website, because now I don't know what you try do.

Comment: Hi, the entirety of the code is posted above, this is a pared down example that replicates the problem. Create an HTML file using the exact code above, set any image as your source, navigate to it on an iPhone/iPhone emulator and you'll see the issue I'm having.

Comment: ok no problem I'll be waiting, ps you can create example on fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about more examples. What you try to do is currently not possible due to a restrictive policy from Apple. "Inline" video (official term) is prohibited on iPhones. It will work on iPads though. There is a workaround but it requires the website to be in in a container App. 
You will encounter the same problem on all androids before version 3.1

The video will always play in the native QuickTime Player and indeed is covering any layer you put on top of it - even though you are able to see it while the video is paused, you touch events are usually caught by QuickTime

For more info please check my other answers - I'm on my mobile right now...

Comment: Thanks Jörn, suspected as much, good to know about Android too. Could you provide a link or any more info re wrapping the site in a container App?

Comment: www.phonegap.com seems to be the solution though I haven't actually tried it. It actually allows web-apps to use device APIs that are usually only available to native apps. It probably has a function to enable inline video as well (if that's not the default). Also check out https://build.phonegap.com/ which allows you to develop apps without having the compiler installed - that's done on their servers =) some more info your specific topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/F7y_5XtyejQ